# get unique root links from a directory of symlinks

Tags: linux, bash, shell, symlink, ln

I have a largish directory filled with symlinks (created using `ln-s`) - about 1million of them. They look like so:

```
--img_dir
  -- img.jpg --> /path/to/some/img.jpg
  -- imgc.jpg --> /path/to/some/imgc.jpg
  -- imgd.jpg --> /path/to/some/imgd.jpg
  -- img2.jpg --> /path2/to2/some2/img2.jpg
  -- img3.jpg --> /path3/to3/some3/img3.jpg
  -- img21.jpg --> /path21/to21/some21/img2.jpg
  -- img31.jpg --> /path31/to31/some31/img3.jpg
<snip>
```

for record keeping purposes, I would like a list of unique `base_dirs` (the root directories) from which the symlinks have been created.

So, I would like the following output:

```
/path/to/some
/path2/to2/some2
/path3/to3/some3
/path21/to21/some21
/path31/to31/some31
```

I tried googling around to see how one can achieve this in bash but I am not able to find anything useful..

Any help or pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `find` can list symlinks
- `realpath` turns symlinks into absolute paths
- `dirname` strips final component from a path
- `sort` sorts lines and can dedupe

```
find img_dir -type l | xargs realpath | xargs dirname | sort -u
```

Or, logging errors:

```
find img_dir -type l 2>find-errs     |
xargs realpath       2>realpath-errs |
xargs dirname        2>dirname-errs  |
sort -u               >basedir-list
```

Some implementations of `realpath` and `dirname` may only allow a single argument. In that case, do

```
... | xargs -I@ realpath @ | xargs -I@ dirname @ | ...
```

---

The code above assumes no really wierd paths (eg. mustn't contain newlines).

Comment: If using GNU find, `-printf "%l\n"` will give you the target of a symbolic link so you can skip the `realpath` part.

Comment: @Shawn note that this will not detect broken symlinks; if used, something like `find -xtype l -ls >broken-links` could be useful

Comment: So? That's not in the problem description.

Comment: answers aren't just for the person who asked the question :-)